# Javascript Slide-In Onload

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, pageload

So I'm trying to have a div slide in on pageload. It has an id of "#crazyslide" and is absolutely positioned to the right -800px in the css.

So I used this code in the head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {          
$("#crazyslide").animate( { right: '0px' }, 2000 ); 
});
</script>
```

Shouldn't this work?

Comment: What is happening, not happening? Any console errors? Where is your script in relation to your HTML?

Comment: Yes that looks ok - maybe provide your html? Also, if you have an image within #crazyslide - document.ready may be firing too early. In that case, you would need $(window).load(function etc.

Comment: create a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Your problem [isn't reproducible](http://jsfiddle.net/n677j1np/) with the code you've provided.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't hide it off the edge of the screen. Devices like mobiles will let people scroll past the edge and it will look bad.

I recommend using this example of hiding and showing it with javascript.
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_hide_show

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should. I just tested with your exact code, and it worked fine. There are ways to prevent a parent element from showing scroll bars for offscreen content.

- Check to be sure your div is properly named:   (console.log($("#crazyslide"));
- Be sure a parent element's css isn't preventing the div from being
  shown at all, such as a strange body width or something.
- Be sure the div has content, and a set width.

*This turned out to be a load order issue where jquery was not yet defined when the animation code was called.

Comment: Here's the page I'm referring to: snocobra.staging.wpengine.com. The box at the top "call for more information" is supposed to slide in. I have it partially on the screen right now so that I can see if it's even displaying, which it is, but the css does not change to 0 to the right, and remains -300

Comment: "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" Try putting the script element which contains the crazyslide animation after the element which loads jquery which I believe is loading at line 83.

Comment: Good catch, but still doesn't fix the problem...now the script element is right next to </head> but still no results.

Comment: Ah, forget this; development deadline is hit; I ended up using animate.css for this..